# view in xml layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

I've created my own view and I can't figure out how to add it from the main.xml layout file

setContentView(vi); its work but ı want  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

public class Gui extends View {

```
public Gui(Context context) {
    super(context);

}
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {


    Paint myPaint = new Paint();
    Paint myPaintFill= new Paint();


    myPaintFill.setColor(Color.GREEN);

    myPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    myPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    myPaint.setStrokeWidth(1);


    RectF r = new RectF(0,0,50,50);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(r, 0, 0, myPaint);



    }

 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your custom `View` is an inner class in your `Activity` the java compiler will output the name `ActivityName$GraphicsView` for that class. You can't use that name directly as the `View` name in the xml layout because of the `$` character but you can do it like this:

```
<view 
    class="com.package.here.ActivityName$GraphicsView"
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

where `ActivityName` is the name of the activity where your `GraphicsView` class is declared.

Comment: @user2960472 You could accept my answer if it helped! Tick my answer as green